# ImportError: No module named github3 on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Working with : Ubuntu 13.10  installed with python

```
Python 2.7.5+.
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import github3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named github3
>>>
```

Trying to install github3.py   getting "ImportError:"
I have no clue what is going on . I am new to python and installing this to try to learn this language .  Let me know if anyone has input.

Comment: The problem still persist on ubuntu 20.04 with `python3-github` package installed:    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (github3.py >= 1.0.0a3) on hosts's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install the *github3.py* library before you can import it.

From your linux shell try:
`sudo pip install github3.py` (sudo only if you are admin, to install it system-wide)

It should work afterwards.

Comment: I installed this version for Ansible (didn't need to install it system-wide). I wonder why would anyone install pip modules with elevated privileges anyways

Answer (score 0):

`pip install github3.py`

or

`git clone git://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py.git github3.py`

`cd github3.py`

`python setup.py install`

https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

Working with : Kali Linux

Currently the 'github3' module is not working in python version 2.7...
I also get this error!

```
└─$ python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jul 14 2021, 08:11:37)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import github3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named github3
```

But by python 3 I managed to get out of the error!

```
└─$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import github3
>>> exit()
```

It is likely that this module is only compatible with python 3 now....https://pypi.org/project/github3.py/

Answer (score 0):

```
python3    

Python 3.9.10 (main, Feb 22 2022, 13:54:07) 
[GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import github3
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>> exit()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).